# Why is this returning "Unfortunately your app has crashed"?

Tags: java, android

I am absolutely new and I am learning coding from the new boston.

The MainActivity.java:

```
package com.tipsoftech.fastfart;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer fartsound = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
            R.raw.fartsound);
    Button fartnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFartNow);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Full screen Open
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // Full screen Close



        fartnow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                fartsound.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bFartNow"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/fartnow" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am quite positive that I did not mess up the @drawable/ stuffs. But whenever I try to run the app on the emulator, It says "Unfortuantely, Fast Fart has crashed.". I am not sure what is happenning and I would really love it if some one helped me out. I am a new developer and I am only 14. Please help me out.

Comment: Using logcat will tell you what happened in the code to make it crash http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html you can also view it directly in eclipse using window > show view > logcat. That will give you a stack trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to retrieve your UI elements after inflating your layout, otherwise `findViewById` returns `null` and hence the `NullPointerException` at the line `fartnow.setOnClickListener` which make your app crashing.

Here's how to fix it :

```
Button fartnow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //layout inflated
        fartnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFartNow); //now it's ok
```

As pointed out in comments, [`requestWindowFeature`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29) **must** be call before `setContentView()`

Note that you should always read/post your stacktrace when you have such an error, it should tell you the line where it occurs and it will be easier for you to debug your app.

Comment: Also, `requestWindowFeature` needs to be called *before* `setContentView()`

Comment: Still the Unfortunately, Fast Fart has stopped!

Comment: @user3177771 Post the updated code and the stacktrace. Or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Write this line after setContentView() methos in your onCreate() method-

```
fartnow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFartNow);
```